# Error Yii2 when I try apply migration "Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'could not find driver'

Tags: sql, yii2, migration, alter-column

I try to apply migration in Yii2. Before I created her successfully.
I need to change table column 'enum'.
I got this error: "Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'could not find driver'". What did I wrong? Thank all!

My code:

```
public function up()
{
    $this->alterColumn('{{%Payments}}', 'return_reason', "enum('0','1','2','3','4') DEFAULT NULL");
}

public function down()
{
    echo "m170208_083749_alter_column_return_reason_payment cannot be reverted.\n";

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you got `db` component configured for console application?

Comment: I think YES. Coz I created migration

Comment: You can create migration without `db`. Check your console config.

Comment: How can I do this? I'm just start learn Yii2. So... "so-so"))

Comment: If this is based on Basic Template see `/config/console.php`. In case of Advanced Template it can be `/console/config/main.php` or `main-local.php` or `/common/config/main.php` or `main-local.php`. Look for `db` key in `components` - there should be database configuration.

Comment: I got the resolve... In general. On my ubuntu was checked php version 7.. and I just change version on 5.6. 
Thank all for answer guys! And sorry for my "english" )

Comment: Probably you are missing an extension for the db driver(eg. pdo, pdo_mysql) for php7. You need to install this and enable it for cli.

Comment: I switched php verion on 5.6(it version that I need). But u're right. Thanx!